# Grails, casting error when retrieving a record

Tags: sql-server, database, grails, data-retrieval

I created a new domain and created the table manually.
The table should only contain one record so the only record id will be (1).

The record should be created automatically if not exist but I always get a casting error when trying to retrieve the record. It doesn't matter if I create the record manually first - the get, find or whatever always return in error.

The code that fails:

```
    def int id = 1
    def WtStatus wts = WtStatus.get(id)?:new WtStatus(id:1).save(failOnError:true)
```

The domain:

```
class WtStatus {
  def prodBufferService
  int     weekUpdated
  Date    dateUpdated

  def beforeInsert() {
      dateUpdated = new Date()
      weekUpdated = prodBufferService.getCurrentYearWeek()
  }
  def beforeUpdate() {
      dateUpdated = new Date()
  }
  static constraints = {
      dateUpdated     nullable:true
      weekUpdated     nullable:true
  }

  static mapping = {
      table   'wt_status'
      version true
      id              column: "id",              type:        'int'
  }
```

}

The create-script for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[wt_status](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [version] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [date_updated] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [week_updated] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__wt_statu__3213E83F77809FC6] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

STACKTRACE:

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.IntegerTypeDescriptor.unwrap(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:19)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:248)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:2051)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:2020)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1950)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1903)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1881)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2622)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2605)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2434)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2429)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.internal.CriteriaImpl.uniqueResult(CriteriaImpl.java:385)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi$_get_closure1.doCall(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:79)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:243)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:187)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.execute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:110)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.get(AbstractHibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:75)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.get(GormEntity.groovy:518)
    at com.buffer.OrdersAndStoreController$$EQIjps9c.list(OrdersAndStoreController.groovy:29)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the type you are using for your `ìd` variable, which is `int`. Since you did not declare the `id` property in the domain, it will be a `Long` (Grails default). Note: in the mapping block you only define what will be the relation with the database, that's why the property is still a `Long` in the domain.

Also, you don't need to use `def` if you're going to use another type for a variable. Try this:

```
Long id = 1
WtStatus wts = WtStatus.get(id)?:new WtStatus(id:1).save(failOnError:true)
```

Comment: I noticed what you said about declaring the id so: Because of that your solution didn't work, I still got the same error, I declared the id as int and the whole thing started to work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks too complicated. I think what you really want is:

```
WtStatus wts = WtStatus.findOrSaveById( id )
```

as per [ref-doc](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveBy.html)

Also, you should explicitelt define the `id` field to be of `Integer` type. Otherwise GORM treats those as `Long` by default.

Comment: Did exactly what you said, but I got the same error. See my amendment above:

Comment: See my comment above how I fixed it. Your code snippet is very nice. I'll be using it from now.